# Set datetime with random trailing nanoseconds to zero's

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have multiple dates in a table with the following date format, example:

```
2016-01-03 12:04:00.0123123
```

I need to update the entire table to update all the trailing mili and nanoseconds to zero's

So the above date should become:

```
2016-01-03 12:04:00.0000000
```

is there anyone that can assist me with this update script?

thx in advance

Comment: What data types is the column datetime/datetime2?

Comment: Why do you need to set them all to 0 in the first place? That seems kind of counterproductive because you are removing potentially valuable information from your database. Maybe what you really want is to do this when you retrieve the data (i.e formatting which belongs in the front end)

Comment: its datetime2. It really needs to be changed because certain applications we are using cannot handle when the mili/nanoseconds are <> 0  and crash. It's not less valuable to us when they are changed to all zero's.

Comment: @TheGameiswar its not a duplicate, the mili/nanoseconds don't need to be truncated, just updated to zero's

Comment: Why not just change the datatype to datetime then? Or convert it when you retrieve it?

Comment: try the first answer in referenced link

Comment: What makes you think truncating isn't the same as zeroing them? After all, `1` is the same values as `1.0000000000000000000000`

Comment: Yes, functionally it may be the same, but i need the zero's to show. Obviously.

Comment: Then you either misunderstand how date values work or your consuming system is very badly written.

Comment: Not really. We took this dateformat for all dates in our entire database, but in a certain table that is used within an MVC application these nanoseconds have to be all zero, else the viewmodel crashes. I don't get why I get all this feedback for my datatype choices and duplicate marks when all I did was ask for assistance with writing an update script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **decoding and encoding the values while ommiting the milliseconds** should do the trick:

```
UPDATE table
  SET field = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    DATEPART(year, field),
    DATEPART(month, field),
    DATEPART(day, field),
    DATEPART(hour, field),
    DATEPART(minute, field),
    DATEPART(second, field),
    0);
```

The decoding is done with [`DATEPART()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql). For the encoding [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql) is used.
If your field is of type `DATETIME2` you would use [`DATETIME2FROMPARTS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetime2fromparts-transact-sql).

Comment: Brilliant! thanks alot, that works great

Comment: @ImperialBert Just seems like a long way to go where one expression will suffice  Update table Set field = format(field ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')